# htmlspecialchars outputting blank

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

Using both htmlspecialchars and htmlentities is causing blank outputs from items such as a `™` symbol and even single `'` quotes.  Obviously, this is absolutely useless, however outputting the data without using html characters results in this symbol for both �.  Any reason why this is occuring?

here is the code that is causing the problem:

```
<p>
<?php 
    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($aboutarray[0]['about_us'], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")); 
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Sounds like a charset issue. Are you sure that your data is UTF-8-encoded?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your problem, but I tried this on ideone.com and it seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/P298n

Comment: @EmilVikström How do I go about making sure of this?

Comment: @EricH yeah it works fine on one of my websites, but for the other with identical code it outputs incorrectly.

Comment: @JimmyBanks You might could try `utf8_encode()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Where is `$aboutarray[0]['about_us']` coming from?

Comment: This will give you the byte sequence of the string: `for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) printf('%d ', ord($string[$i]));`

Comment: @EricH using utf8_encode worked, now im confused why this is necessary on one site, but on the other the text outputs properly from the get-go?

Comment: @deceze i didnt include the query for the array, but the value is text and I have confirmed output without using `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`

Comment: The collation in the database is utf8_general_ci

Comment: If `utf8_encode` worked, that means the data was actually encoded in Latin-1. You may want to read this: http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: What's the connection charset (set during connection to the database)?

Comment: The data i took was copy pasted from an old site (migrating the site, not stealing anything).  Would that be a possible reason that the text from the site was encoded in Latin?

Comment: @EmilVikström in the header of the site i have the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`, as for the database connection I am using ADODB which doesnt have any issues on the first site.  I havent specified a encoding as far as i know.

Comment: upon further inspection, utf8_encode is just removing the trademark symbol

Comment: @JimmyBanks Check out `mb_detect_encoding()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php or `mb_check_encoding()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php.  Those may be of assistance in tracking down the issue.

Answer (score 14):

That string is not encoded in valid UTF-8 encoding. It could be in another encoding like UTF-16 or perhaps it just contains some binary junk that doesn't correspond to any format.

The bottom line is that, since you specified "UTF-8" as the encoding type parameter of htmlspecialchars(), it will return an empty string if the string does not comply with "UTF-8".  It states this in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

A simple fix is to use the substitute or ignore flag.  Change:

```
htmlspecialchars($aboutarray[0]['about_us'], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")
```

To:

```
htmlspecialchars($aboutarray[0]['about_us'], ENT_COMPAT|ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8")
```

Or:

```
htmlspecialchars($aboutarray[0]['about_us'], ENT_COMPAT|ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8")
```

**Note: ENT_IGNORE removes the non-compliant bytes.  This could cause [a security issue](http://unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Deletion_of_Noncharacters).**  It's better to truly understand the contents of your string and how it's being encoded.  Correct the source of the problem rather than use the simple ENT_IGNORE fix.

You should ask yourself *why* your string is not encoded in UTF-8... it *should* be, but it's not.

I happen to have just encountered this problem as well; you can read details on why an empty string is being returned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705829/htmlspecialchars-causing-text-to-disapear).

Comment: P.S. I would also suggest changing ENT_COMPAT to ENT_QUOTES, but as always, I suppose that depends on your specific scenario.