# uploaded file oppening error

Tags: php, upload

I just created upload script but i have got problem after uploading files

I can see them like this:

[image]

After opening file number 1 file is opening perfectly, but problem is when i touch file 2
because this file have spaces or special symbols in name, and opens like this

[image]

here is my php files

```
<?php

$target_dir = "uploads/up/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;

$FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}


// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000000000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}




// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has 
been             uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```

show.php

```
<?php
$sub = ($_GET['dir']);
$path = 'up';
$path = $path . "$sub";
$dh = opendir($path);
$i=1;







while (($file = readdir($dh)) !==   false) {
if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
    if (substr($file, -4, -3) =="."){


echo "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($path$result)."'>".$file."</a><br>";

    }
    $i++;
}
}

closedir($dh);
?>
```

Comment: If you want help you will need to put you code here.

Comment: Please post code as text

Comment: `urlencode()` is the way to go! If you have spaces in a name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `show.php` here:

```
<a href='$path$result'>
```

The `'` int he file name is the same used in your `href` parameter, which breaks it.

Use `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid this problem.

```
echo "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($path.$result)."'>".$file."</a><br>";
```

Comment: Parse error: parse error in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\uploads\index.php on line 19

line 19 -- echo "<a href='".htmlspecialchars($path$result)."'>".$file."</a><br>";

Comment: Change `$path$result` to `$path.$result`, sorry. Edited my post.

Comment: now it opens like this [link}(http://www.picz.ge/img/s3/1412/24/4/4fb4c7c58f72.png)

Comment: I don't know, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210413/htmlspecialchars-outputting-blank

Comment: i just understand thas because file name "Gigi D' Agostino_ Blablabla.mp3" contains ' afted gigi D and it makes php brake